# EJB retrieving duplicate rows

Tags: java, jsf, jpa, ejb

I have a weird problem. When I create rows from the view in the database, it does that fine, and shows very nice. but sometimes it retrieves a duplicate row and whatever row I add the same duplicate row will appear again and again. However, when I redeploy the application the problem is solved and the rows are shown properly again until the entry crashes again resulting in the same problem. I can't figure out what is going on as there are no errors. I'm using EJB 3.0, glassfish 3.1.1, JSF 2.0, EclipseLink, and JavaDB.

[image: the above one is the row in the database, the below one is in the IDE]

[image: this is how it looks like in the view]

this is my persisting code:

```
@Override
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void create(Carrier carrier) {
            em.persist(c.getObject());
            em.flush();
          }
    }
```

and this is my retrieving code:

```
o@Override
public List<CrpPaypoint> getPaypoints() {
    Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT c FROM CrpPaypoint c ORDER BY c.levelOrder.levelOrder");
    List<CrpPaypoint> list = q.getResultList();
    return list;
}


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="hrtestPU" transaction-type="JTA">
     <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
     <jta-data-source>jdbc/hrdb</jta-data-source>
     <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
     <properties>
        <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables"/>
     </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
```

Comment: Would it perhaps have something to do with the fact that they both begin with identical strings, but that the last one just has one more character?

Comment: Do you have a persistence.xml file, if so could you show it please?

Comment: If you change the last two records, will it still create the same issue?

Comment: @gobernador Whenever this issue happens whatever I add it will add correctly in the database, but it shows duplicate results on retrieving. For example if I added HHA-WWW-XXX, and HHA-WWW-YYY in db will be stored as entered.. but in the view the last two will be HHA-WWW-YYY (the xxx will show as yyy as will) and if I added a third one (HHa-WWW-ZZZ) the last three will show as HHA-WWW-ZZZ. If I redeployed the application, then EJB shows them currectly as stored (xxx, yyy, and zzz).

Comment: @esej I have updated the question please see the presistence.xml file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be somehow corrupting the objects in the shared cache.

To disable the shared cache see,

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/FAQ/How_to_disable_the_shared_cache%3F

Check how you are adding the objects to the collection, ensure your new objects have unique ids, ensure you are not adding the same object twice, or changing the existing objects.

Include your code for how to edit the objects.

Comment: I'm directly retrieving from the db to the view in a datatable without any interruption, and they do have unique ids (the id is the code itself). I'm going to disable the shared cache and see what happens.

Comment: I have tried to refresh the cache before retrieving and until now it looks fine as the issue did not appear yet. However, I cannot take it for granted that the problem is solved because as I said it appears "sometimes" and not every time. I'm gonna try it for couple of days and update you, I hope this is the solution.